# Get List items by specific content type from site and subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, typescript

I'm trying to extract list data from a site (with REST query) and its subsites based on their content type and put everything in a different list.

For example from https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteA, https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteA/siteB and so on.

The content type is custom made, lets call it CT1 with ID 0x011100F324658D0CFE9E46B6B8FD21A38FE5A7

I'm trying to get all list from my site A and its subsites with the ID of the content type im looking for like this:

```
             /_api/search/query? 
          querytext='ContentTypeId:0x011100F324658D0CFE9E46B6B8FD21A38FE5A7* 
         + path:https://mytenant/sites/siteA*'&selectproperties='Title,Path'
```

But this doesn't return anything at all.

Comment: Please refer to my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try below url:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentTypeId:0x011100F324658D0CFE9E46B6B8FD21A38FE5A7*+path:https://mytenant/sites/siteA/*'&selectproperties='Title,Path'
```

"/" was missing in the sitecollection url.